# Plesk 12 Linux Server Mail Spam Issue

Tags: linux, email, spam

I'm running multiple websites on my dedicated server, and for one website in particular where users signup and then must verify their email address, I'm getting reports from my client that a small number of people aren't receiving the confirmation email message and as such are not being registered with the website. Whenever I test it though I receive the emails through totally fine, so I'm having trouble determining the issue.

Comment: Start with looking in your email logs.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to check /var/log/maillog once this kind of issue is reported by the customer? Try to search customer's email to see if it's a mail service which does not send a notification for some reason. You may also find some useful info on why it's not sent.

Be aware that the log gets rotated. In case you need to check the log for specific date in the past look for something like /var/log/maillog-20140615.

Kate.